# How to optimize where clause query that contains to_char

Tags: mysql, oracle

i need to optimize the where clause query to cut down the cost when i use explain plan.

Below is the original statement

```
create index idx on orders(o_orderdate)

select *
from orders
where (to_char(o_orderdate, 'dd-mon-yy') = '23-MAR-97' and o_totalprice > 2) or (not o_custkey > 3 and to_char(o_orderdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy') = '23-MAR-1997');
```

[image: original]

This is the explain plan that i get from the original query

But when i try to optimize it using this query

```
select * 
from orders
where o_totalprice > 2
and o_custkey < 3
and o_orderdate >= to_date('23MAR97', 'dd-mon-yy') 
and o_orderdate <= to_date('24MAR1997', 'dd-mon-yyyy');
```

[image: new where optimization]

it return no rows selected

How do i optimize the original where query and still return 4500 rows?

Comment: Any time you put a function on the left side of a comparison (where to_char(my_date)...  you eliminate the possibility of using an index on that column (unless you have a function-based index).  Also, when comparing dates, you need to compare the DATE, not the to_char character representation. Also, be sure to consistently use 4-digit years, Do not re-create the Y2k bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not account for the `OR` properly.  It would be:

```
select *
from orders
where o_orderdate between to_date('23-MAR-1997','DD-MON-YYYY') 
         and to_date('24-MAR-1997','DD-MON-YYYY') - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
and ( o_totalprice > 2
   or not o_custkey > 3 )
;
```

Comment: Hi, its still returned no rows selected

Comment: Sorry -- typo in my query.  I had `23-MAY` instead of `23-MAR`.  Please try it again.

Comment: Thank you! Now the cost goes down to 558 instead of original 2703